# Show select box options on external trigger

Tags: javascript, html, select

Can anyone explain to me how to trigger the "open" event on a select box ?

I've seen many sites hide select boxes and trigger it to open when clicking a div. Unify.js does this. I've gone through every line of code in Unify and I can't find out how to do it

Thanks

Comment: Click on it, there is no standard javascript way of opening a select element. You can create one programatically to behave however you want, but you can't do it with a standard DOM element.

Comment: you can expand a select by changing the 'size' attribute. eg, $(selectElement).attr("size",selectElement[0].options.length); but it's not ideal as you have scroll bars that you have to hack away with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sleeping on it, I realized that plugins like Unify don't trigger the select element to open. Rather, the real select box is placed over the faux-select box and set to 0 opacity. This gives the impression of a javascript even being triggered when in fact you're just clicking/tapping an invisible select element.